# 554 Bad PTR Record but Record exists and is correct

Tags: email-server, ptr-record

I'm getting Error messages from my freshly setup Postfix Server about impossible connections like this.

> 554-kundenserver.de (mxeue005) Nemesis ESMTP Service not available
>   554-No SMTP service
>   554-Bad DNS PTR resource record.

`dig -x IP` says PTR is set to lvpsxx-xxx-xxx-xxx.dedicated.hosteurope.de.
Telnet to IP with Port 25 ends with 
"220 lvpsxx-xxx-xxx-xxx.dedicated.hosteurope.de ESMTP Postfix"
so obviously the Server Name is set correctly.

The only thing I can think of right now is that somehow Cloudflare DNS is responsible, although I can't explain how because Cloudflare only manages the several other domains running on the machine, the "lvpsxx-xxx-xxx-xxx.dedicated.hosteurope.de" and it's DNS is provided by the hosting provider.

Anyone have any idea what the Problem could be?

Comment: The 554 lines you quote look like they are actually just a part of an SMTP reply from a server your server tried to deliver mail to. Can you please edit your question to include the _complete_ SMTP transcript?

Answer (score 1):

The remote mailserver thinks you are coming from a dialup connection with a dynamic IP because of the format of the reverse DNS pointer with the encoded IP and rejects the connection.

We had the same problem with a VPS at HostEurope. That seems to be a heuristic to fight spam that United Internet started using rather recently.

To work around this, change the reverse DNS PTR for the VPS to point to your own domain in the HostEurope control panel: 
https://kis.hosteurope.de/administration/ip-netze/index.php

See also https://faq.hosteurope.de/?cpid=11518 (German)

Of course, you can also try to convince United Internet to adjust their heuristic or wait until somebody else does. But this will probably take some time.